# Conditions for null-homotopic chain map in a specific example

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I am trying to calculate the ring $Ext^{\bullet}_R(k,k)$ where $R=k[x,y]/(xy)$ and $k$ is regarded as an $R$-module via $x$ and $y$ acting as zero. I thought I was done but then to my demise I found a hole in my argument. The way I'm going about it is by identifying $Ext^n_R(k,k)$ with chain maps $P_\bullet\longrightarrow P_\bullet[-n]$ modulo null-homotpy, where $P_\bullet$ is the following projective resolution of $k$.
$$\dots\overset{\phi}\rightarrow R\oplus R\overset{\theta}\rightarrow R\oplus R\overset{\phi}\rightarrow R\oplus R\overset{\psi}\rightarrow R\rightarrow k\rightarrow 0$$ where $\phi$ and $\theta$ alternate, $\phi:(1,0)\mapsto (y,0),\ (0,1)\mapsto (0,x)$, $\theta:(1,0)\mapsto (x,0),\ (0,1)\mapsto (0,y)$, $\psi:(1,0)\mapsto x,\ (0,1)\mapsto y$

I am going to describe my question just for the case where $n$ is odd. Let $f_\bullet:P_\bullet\longrightarrow P_\bullet [-n]$ be a chain map. Then have $$f_n(1,0)y=f_{n+1}^{(1)}(1,0)x+f_{n+1}^{(2)}(1,0)y\ \ \ \ f_n(0,1)x=f_{n+1}^{(1)}(0,1)x+f_{n+1}^{(2)}(0,1)y$$ $$(x,x)f_{n+i}(1,0)=(y,x)f_{n+i+1}(1,0)\ \ \ \ (y,y)f_{n+i}(0,1)=(y,x)f_{n+i+1}(0,1)\ \ \ \text{for $i\geq 1$ odd}$$ $$(y,y)f_{n+i}(1,0)=(x,y)f_{n+i+1}(1,0)\ \ \ \ (x,x)f_{n+i}(0,1)=(x,y)f_{n+i+1}(0,1)\ \ \ \text{for $i\geq 1$ even} $$ Now $h_\bullet$ is a null-homotpy of $f_\bullet$ iff $$f_n(1,0)=h_{n-1}(1,0)x+h_n^{(1)}(1,0)x+h_n^{(2)}(1,0)y\ \ \ f_n(0,1)=h_{n-1}(0,1)y+h_n^{(1)}(0,1)x+h_n^{(2)}(0,1)y$$ $$f_{n+i}(1,0)=(y,y)h_{n+i-1}(1,0)+(y,x)h_{n+i}(1,0)\ \ \ f_{n+i}(0,1)=(x,x)h_{n+i-1}(0,1)+(y,x)h_{n+i}(0,1)\ \text{for $i\geq 1$ odd}$$ $$f_{n+i}(1,0)=(x,x)h_{n+i-1}(1,0)+(x,y)h_{n+i}(1,0)\ \ \ f_{n+i}(0,1)=(y,y)f_{n+i-1}(0,1)+(x,y)h_{n+i}(0,1)\ \text{for $i\geq 1$ even}$$ We see that if $f_\bullet$ is null-homotopic then we have the following conditions (C):$$f_n(1,0),\ f_n(0,1)\in <x,y>\vartriangleleft R$$ $$f_{n+i}(1,0)\in <(y,y),(y,x)>\vartriangleleft R\oplus R\ \ \ f_{n+i}(0,1)\in <(x,x),(y,x)>\vartriangleleft R\oplus R\ \text{for $i\geq 1$ odd}$$ $$f_{n+i}(1,0)\in <(x,x),(x.y)>\vartriangleleft R\oplus R\ \ \ f_{n+i}(0,1)\in <(y,y),(x,y)>\vartriangleleft R\oplus R\ \text{for $i\geq 1$ even}$$ At first I thought I showed that conditions (C) are also sufficient for $f_\bullet$ to be null-homotopic but I found an error that I cannot fix and I'm sensing that these conditions might actually not be sufficient. **How can I come up with sufficient conditions for $f_\bullet$ to be null-homotopic?**
Also if these conditions are in fact sufficient (and the corresponding ones for the case $n$ is even) I get that the ring in question is $R$

Comment: I don't understand what your question is...? The resolution you wrote is minimal, so when you take hom with $\mathbb k$ over $R$ you get zero differential and immediately that $\mathrm{Ext}$ is two dimensional in all positive degrees. Why do you want to compute it with $\mathrm{End}(P)$ instead, when $\mathrm{Hom}(P,\mathbb k)$ is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Approach 1: minimal resolution*: consider a building a resolution of $\mathbb k$ by hand, which you can choose to be a periodic Koszul resolution, as you did:

$$\xrightarrow{\phantom{m}\cdots\phantom{m}} R^2 \xrightarrow{\left[\begin{matrix} 0 & y\\x & 0 \end{matrix}
\right]} R^2 \xrightarrow{\left[\begin{matrix} 0 & y\\x & 0 \end{matrix}
\right]}  R^2 \xrightarrow{\left[\begin{matrix} x \\y \end{matrix}
\right]}  R \longrightarrow 0 $$

This resolution is minimal, in the sense that taking $\mathrm{Hom}$
with $\mathbb k$ yields a zero differential. Since the resulting complex is just

$$\xrightarrow{\phantom{m}0\phantom{m}} \mathbb k^2 \xrightarrow{\phantom{m}0\phantom{m}} \mathbb k^2 \xrightarrow{\phantom{m}0\phantom{m}} \mathbb k^2 \xrightarrow{\phantom{m}0\phantom{m}} \mathbb k\longrightarrow 0 $$

this immediately tells you that $\mathrm{Ext}_R^n(\mathbb k,
\mathbb k)$ is two dimensional for all $n\geqslant 2$. Moreover,
you can show that the augmentation $\varepsilon:P\longrightarrow \mathbb k$ induces a quasi-iso $\varepsilon_*:\mathrm{End}(P) \to \mathrm{Hom}(P,\mathbb k)$, so you don't have to compute the homology of the endomorphism complex by hand.

*Approach 2: Koszul duals.*
There is a simpler approach to computing $\mathrm{Ext}$ in this case.

Namely, if you consider $A = \mathbb k[x,y]/(xy)$, then this is a monomial associative algebra presented by $x$ and $y$ modulo two relations $xy=0$ and $yx=0$ (note that $xy-yx=0$ can be replaced by the second once since $xy=0$). That is, $A= \mathbb k\langle x,y\rangle / (xy,yx)$.

In this case, the normal forms (things not divisible by $xy$ or $yx$) are $1$ and $x^n,y^n$ for $n\geqslant 1$, so the kernel of multiplication by $x$ is the ideal generated by $y$, and the kernel of multiplication by $y$ is the ideal generated by $x$.

Having said this, quadratic monomial algebras are Koszul, the Koszul dual in this case is $\mathbb k\langle x,y\rangle/(x^2,y^2)$, since all binomials are $xy,yx,y^2,x^2$, and we merely need to pick those not appearing in the presentation of $A$. Hence, $\mathrm{Ext}_A(\mathbb k,\mathbb k)$ as an algebra is isomorphic to this algebra.

*Approach 3: Anick chains:* For monomial algebras, there is a [completely combinatorial way](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2000383) to compute the Yoneda (co)algebra.
In this case, the monomial relations are $xy$ and $yx$, and the $n$-chains are equal to the two element set
$$C_n = \{ X_n = x(yx)^{n-1}, Y_n = y(xy)^{n-1}\}$$
for all $n\geqslant 1$. The Anick resolution then is of the form
$(R\otimes C_\bullet ,d)$ so that $R\otimes C_n = R^2$ for all $n\geqslant 1$ and the differential is $dX_n = x\otimes Y_{n-1}$ and $dY_n = y\otimes X_{n-1}$, i.e. this is isomorphic to the resolution you found, and the resolution given by Koszul duality (because one is dealing with quadratic monomial algebras here).

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm afraid I'm not familiar with approaches 2 and 3 yet but I'll try and look into them. Also in approach 1 how does one compute the Yoneda product without going through the step outlined in my original post? The definition of Yoneda product I know involves composition of  chain maps modulo null-homotopy.

Comment: @AlexG Hi Alex, sorry, I did not answer your question regarding the Yoneda product. It is not extremely easy to compute generically, but in your situation you can learn about Koszul duality to compute it i.e. show that the Ext groups are generated in degree 1 by two classes $x,y$ and that all relations follow from $x^2=y^2=0$.

Comment: In your case, because $P$ is periodic, it should actually be easy to compute lifts $X,Y$ of the degree 1 generators $x,y$ of the cohomology of $\hom(P,k)$ to $\hom(P,P)$ (through the map $\hom(P,P)\to \hom(P,k)$ and then just compute the usual compositions to check that $XYX\ldots$ and $YXY\ldots$ give the generators in each degree.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I was actually able to find sufficient conditions for the map to be null-homotopic and they gave me the required chain maps modulo null-homotopy and they agree with what you wrote in your last comment. In the end the ext ring is just $k<x,y>/(x^2,y^2)$

Comment: @AlexG glad it helped! Consider upvoting in that case. :)